# JQuery - Browse <img> which are child of a specified div

Tags: jquery

i have a div, and i'll browse each  elements child of this div.

html page :

```
<div class="articleviewphoto1"> 
    <div class="articleviewphoto1small"> 
        <a href="#" onClick="loadPhoto('53')"><img src="./articles/photos/1284393671790/1284393671790-1.jpg" class="photoartsb" id="53" /></a> 
    </div> 

    <div class="articleviewphoto1small"> 
        <a href="#" onClick="loadPhoto('54')"><img src="./articles/photos/1284393671790/1284393671790-2.jpg" class="photoartsb" id="54" /></a> 
    </div> 

    <div class="articleviewphoto1small"> 
        <a href="#" onClick="loadPhoto('55')"><img src="./articles/photos/1284393671790/1284393671790-3.jpg" class="photoartsb" id="55" /></a> 
    </div> 

    <div class="articleviewphoto1small"> 
        <a href="#" onClick="loadPhoto('56')"><img src="./articles/photos/1284393671790/1284393671790-4.jpg" class="photoartsb" id="56" /></a> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

(javascript page)

```
function loadPhoto(mexid) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: './auth/ajax.php',
        data: 'idp='+escape(mexid)+'&id=loadphoto',
        success: function(msg) {
            $('.articleviewphoto1').children('img').each(function(){
                $(this).removeClass().addClass('photoarts');
            });
            $('#visualizator').html('somethings ('+msg+')</a>');
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

how can browse these elements? (withous using ids from  tag). i know how to do it if the child are div, but with img?

cheers

Comment: Please show us the HTML markup produced.. not the server-side code.

Comment: ah ok sorry : updated ;)

Comment: You could use `onClick="loadPhoto('53');return false;"` though there are nicer ways, such as binding events using jQuery.

Comment: ah nice!;) and if i want to do this with JQuery code? tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as what Rocket says you could also use the [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method like this:

```
$("div.articleviewphoto1small").find("img")
```

Comment: ah ok, with this method it rocks! tnx:)

Comment: another request tip : i see that if i use "href="#" stat when i click on it, the page go at the top. How can remove this?

Answer (score 0):

`$('div.articleviewphoto1small > img')`

Comment: ive tried, but it doesnt work. i've updated the code, so you can see better what i'm making...

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('.articleviewphoto1small').children()` if there are only images in that div, or `$('.articleviewphoto1small').children('img')` if there are other elements in that div too.